# VB.NET load Excel document into SQL Server database table via code

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, excel

I want to load an Excel document into my VB.NET project and then load all the data from the Excel document into my SQL Server database.

The table name in SQL Server `TCustomers` and it has the following columns:

```
CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, OrderID
```

This is how my data looks in the datagridview:

```
CustomerID   FirstName   LastName   OrderID
01           Jack        Collin       100
```

My Excel table has the data set out in the same way.

```
Cell:  A1 ---- B1 ---- C1 ---- D1
CustomerID----FirstName-LastName-OrderID
 -02 ---- Mike ---- Angel ---- 200
```

I have tried using the following code to accomplish this task but it doesn't do anything:

```
    Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Spreadsheet.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes""")
    ExcelConnection.Open()

    Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

    Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)
    Dim objDataR As OleDbDataReader

    Dim SQLconne As New SqlConnection()
    Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    SQLconne.ConnectionString = ConnString
    SQLconne.Open()

    Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconne)
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TCustomers"

        Try
            objDataR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDataR)
            objDataR.Close()
            SQLconne.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've used SqlBulkCopy objects before and ran into the same problem.

Try explicitly setting up your column mappings. It worked when I did it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Another time IMEX=1 in the connection string worked.

See this question:

[SqlBulkCopy from Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726223/sqlbulkcopy-from-spreadsheet)